# Py2exe confusing errors

Tags: python, module, pygame, executable, py2exe

I'm using Python 2.4 and py2exe version that fits my Python version. My files that I want to make executable are in the Python 2.4 folder in the same directory as its setup.py file.

When I run script (in cmd) `c:\Python24\python.exe setup.py py2exe`, I got bunch of text in my cmd and error like you can see in the picture. Modules are missing and file can't be turned in executable one. I've been having this problem for a very long time and I don't know how to solve it. I need to make my program executable.

Any ideas how to solve this?

[image: Error Image]

**EDIT: i tried with Python, Pygame and Py2exe newer versions (2.6, 2.7, 3.2) and it didn't work. I'm always getting these errors :S 
Also, I've tried with cx_Freeze and again the same :/**

Comment: Why Python 2.4? The console window shows you the stuff that's missing.

Comment: Some of the missing frameworks (Foundation and AppKit) are Mac-frameworks, while you are working on Windows.

Comment: yes, but what to do to prevent this error?

Comment: Does the original python code runs without errors regardless of py2exe?

Comment: yes, it runs perfectly!

Comment: any ideas how to fix this issue?

Comment: how about a list of imports?

Comment: can you create a simple hello world pygame script and make that into an excecutable or does this happen only with your program?

Comment: confusing :S print("Hello world") exe works :S
so the problem is in one of my imports, or?
my imports are:
import pygame, sys, time, random, pyganim, math
import definicije, animacije, stitLijevoAnim, stitSredinaAnim, stitDesnoAnim, plus1Anim 
import plus1AnimLijevo, plus1AnimDesno, destroyEvacAnim, minus20Anim, minus20BcgAnim
from pygame.locals import *

i'm going to try deleting one by one to see where's the problem (of course, I'll skip ones that looks okay)

Comment: so... even I have at lease 1 import (for an example: pygame) cmd will list these errors like on my screenshot above. .exe file works only when there is no imports :S

Comment: edit: I tried something else: when I tried to make exe file from Python 2.6 (not 2.4) version, I didn't get errors like in the screenshow above. However, I got 2 errors (modules missing) and that were "pygame" and "pygame.locals" what is obvious because I didn't install pygame for Python 2.6. When I installed pygame for Python 2.6 and tried to make exe file from my program, again I got errors like on screenshot above ://

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few weeks (had this problem even before) I'm happy to say that I solved this problem! :)

**1st part of my problem** (https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpkjR.png):
I solved it by editing setup.py script with adding "excludes" part in it. That resulted in successful making of executable file!

Modified setup.py script:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
setup(windows=['source_static.py'], options={
          "py2exe": {
              "excludes": ["OpenGL.GL", "Numeric", "copyreg", "itertools.imap", "numpy", "pkg_resources", "queue", "winreg", "pygame.SRCALPHA", "pygame.sdlmain_osx"],
              }
          }
      )
```

So, if you have similar issues, just put those "missing" modules into this "excludes" line.

**2nd part:**

After I succeeded in making of executable file, I had next problem: *"**The application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in unusual way. Please contact...**"*. After days and days of searching and thinking how to solve this another problem, I found a way to do it. I couldn't believe that the problem was so absurd. The problem was in my code, with font definition:

```
font1 = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 13)
```

After changing "**None**" to some system font name (for an example "Arial" (must be a string)), and compiling, I couldn't believe that my .exe file worked!

```
font1 = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 13)
```

Of course, you can use your own font, but you must specify its path and define it in your program.

So for all of you who are experiencing this issues, try this steps and I hope that you will succeed.
I really hope that this will help you, because I've lost days and weeks trying to solve these problems. I even tried making my .exe file with all versions of python and pygame, with many other .exe builders and setup scripts, but without luck. Besides these problems, I had many other problems before but I found answers to them on stackoverflow.com.

I'm happy that I found a way to solve this problems and to help you if you are faced with the same ones.

**Small tips (things I've also done):**

> > 1st: update your Microsoft Visual C++ library to the latest one.
> >
> > 2nd: if you have images or fonts similar that your executable program needs, include them to **dist** folder (where your .exe file has been created).
> >
> > 3rd: when you are making your .exe file, include all needed files to the folder where your setup.py script is (all files and directories that your main script uses).

Used **Python 2.7 x64**, **pygame** and **py2exe**.